Logstash unable to receive all events via single port using beats input
We are facing an issue where we are not able to receive the events concurrently from the servers which are sending events from different beats services like filebeat / metricbeat / winlogbeat using a single beats input module port 5044. While the events arrive in a delayed manner when used this way, we have tried to have it resolved by adding additional input ports like 5045/5046 etc and the events arrive in a much faster way.
Considering that logstash is running on a Linux server, is there any tuning parameters available as such like we can have the log reception via single input ports. or is it ideal and recommended methods to have multiple input ports and distribute the load across?
If anyone have experienced this kind of issue, can you please help with this?
Current config is as below:
input {
  beats{
    port => "5044"
  }
  beats{
    port => "5045"
  }
}


Some of the way to tuning -

Better to check which is heavily under usage, CPU, Memory, IO or Heap. You can follow troubleshoot steps.
Add some profiling on logstash and try to tweak logstash workers, pipeline batch size etc.
There might be chances that incoming traffic is huge so that logstash is not able to process and it creating queue back pressure.
Scale logstash - You can add one more logstash server and add all logstash hosts in filebeat.yml. Enable the loadbalance in filebeat.

